# Disseminating a Visual Studio project

Tags: fortran

I have developed a program using Intel Fortran called from Visual studio, Community Edition 2015.
The Fortran code is a DLL and the final product is a .exe.
I can run this .exe wherever it is located on my computer including from a disc drive. However, when I copy the .exe to another computer, it fails to run.
Obviously I need to prepare the program prior to delivery to another site. I have tried using ClickOnce with no success. What do you suggest?

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Depending on compiler options used when your program is built, you typically need to install the Microsoft C++ and Intel Fortran redistributables onto computers that you want to run the program on.  Your development machine already has these redistributables - they were installed when you installed Visual Studio and the Fortran compiler.

The redistributables for Visual Studio 2015 can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=48145

The redistributables for Intel Fortran can be accessed from https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-compilers-redistributable-libraries-by-version.html

Depending on your circumstances and your method of deployment of your program, you can bundle installation of these redistributables with installation of your program and DLL.

Static linking to the runtime libraries may (exceptions exist) avoid a requirement for the redistributables, but static linking to the runtime is often inappropriate if you are distributing more than a single EXE.